# How to select a column value that corresponds to a row returned by a MySQL aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a table like

```
      date               user_id          page_id
2010-06-19 16:00:00         1                4
2010-06-19 16:00:00         3                4
2010-06-20 07:10:00         1                1
2010-06-20 12:00:10         1                2
2010-06-20 12:00:10         1                3
2010-06-20 13:05:00         2                1
2010-06-20 14:10:00         3                1
2010-06-21 17:00:00         2                1
```

I want to write a query that will return the last page_id for those users who haven't visited in the last day.

So, I can find who hasn't visited in the last day with:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(page_id) 
FROM page_views GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING MAX(date) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

However, how can I find the last viewed page_id for these users? i.e. I want to know which page_id corresponds to the value in the same row as MAX(date). In the case where there are multiple page views per date, I can just select the MAX(page_id).

The expected output from above should be (if NOW() returns 2010-06-21 18:00:00):

```
user_id      page_id
   1            3
   3            1
```

- user_id 1 last visited over a day ago
  at 2010-06-20 12:00:10, and the
  MAX(page_id) was 3.
- user_id 2 last
  visited less than a day ago, so they
  are ignored.
- user_id 3 last visited
  over a day ago, and their most recent
  page_id was 1.

How can I achieve this? I need to use only SQL. I'm using a MySQL derivative that requires all columns in the SELECT clause to be declared in the GROUP BY clause (it's a little more standards compliant).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see different approaches.
For example:

```
select a.user_id, a.page_id
from page_views a
inner join (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) as date
FROM page_views GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING MAX(date) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ) b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
    and a.date = b.date
```

It could be implemented more effective in MS SQL or Oracle with windowed functions.

Another idea:

```
select a.user_id, a.page_id
from page_views a
where date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    and not exist(select 1 from page_views b 
        where a.user_id = b.user_id and b.date > a.date)
```

Comment: I do not know is it possible to have several page_id for the same user_id in the same time.
If yes, you possibly need to add group by to this query

Comment: This is great, thanks. I didn't know you could join on multiple columns, and I'd forgotten about the EXIST keyword.